# Emacs fails to load ruby gems unless invoked from zsh

Tags: ruby, emacs, rvm, debian, bundler

I installed the *bundler* package for emacs and it works fine if emacs is invoked form zsh (terminal).

But when emacs is invoked via some other means, for example (Alt+F2) or the Application menu,

`M-x bundle-install` gives the following error:

> "zsh:1: command not found: bundle"

I believe emacs fails to load some environment variables in the latter case.

*system details:*

Debian (unstable amb64)

rvm 1.17.6

zsh 4.3.17

Comment: You could also invoke the shell with the `--login` switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the solution.
*[rvm](https://github.com/senny/rvm.el)* package is what I needed

```
M-x package-install rvm
M-x rvm-use-default
M-x bundle-install
```

Works like a charm :)
Edit:

Adding the following to init.el make life more easy

```
(rvm-use-default)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on this. I had similar issues with `rvm` too and it seems that it depends on bash or zsh to load properly. The rvm script in `/etc/profile.d` does explicitly check for a "proper" shell and if it is called with `dash` or `sh` it will just not work. Hence `bundle` for example will also no be available as alt-f2 for example uses `sh` to load a program